Overleaf fails to compile from subsection but works from main subsection
I have a main page as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=red, 
pdftitle ={XYZ},
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}



\title{  \\
XYZ \\}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter *{Abstract}

\chapter *{Acknowledgement}


\include{introduction.tex}
\include{method.tex}
\include{simulation.tex}
\include{discussion.tex}
\include{figures.tex}

\appendix
\include{tables.tex}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography/ctm}


\end{document}


The subsection has no preambles e.g. introduction.tex has text like this:
\section{Introduction}

xyz yvz vbjzkjg ks joijjibfhbioif



The errors I have are:
Undefined control sequence.
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

What does this mean? I have the \begin document ..\end document statement on the main page. Do I have to include preambles in all subsections?

you show a warning message that is not an error message and is unrelated to your question. it means that the document did run and produce a pdf, but one line is 20pt wider than it should be. as it's exactly 20pt most likely you have something set to \textwidth wide but it is indented by 20pt at the start of a paragraph, so 20pt too wide overall.

you can not run latex on individual sections, latex always need to run on the main document (normally overleaf will spot only one documen has \documentclass and use that, but perhaps you have multiple files with\documentclass in the project?

if you showed the error rmessage from the log, it would show which command was undefined, and which file it was in. Use a code block so line endings are preserved when showing error messages

@DavidCarlisle I have only one \documentclass on the main page. Also, how can I fix the \textwidth issue?

as I say, somewhere in code you have not shown you have something that is 20pt wider than a space (possibly the page, possibly a table column) that you have not shown, and the fix is to make the thing 20pt smaller or the space 20pt bigger but as we have absolutely no information, we can't tell you what to change.

you can not use \chapter in article class. Doesn't that error for you??

@UlrikeFischer You are right. It is a hangover from a previous version of the document. I will remove them.

the missing begin document error is probably spurious, it just means you have text before \begin{document} but as it follows an undefined command error it may just be the argument of that command, eg \foo{something} would give an error that \foo is undefined then try to typeset something which would give a missing document error. But you have not shown the error message which would show which command is undefined, not provided an example we can run to see the problem.

You'll need to expand the "Undefined control sequence" error and copy/paste that here with the formatting intact.  At the moment, the only "undefined control sequence" that your code gives me is for the \chapter that you say you've removed.
